# Tree ADT implementation in C

Tags: c, tree

As a learning exercise, I decided to implement a BST and add functionality to it slowly. I'd appreciate any feedback.

I should also point out that I borrowed the template from the [here](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/bst/).

`tree.h` header file

```
typedef char treeElement;
typedef struct TreeNodeTag{
  treeElement  element;
  struct TreeNodeTag  *left, *right;
}treeNode;

typedef struct treeCDT{
  treeNode *root;
}treeCDT;

typedef struct treeCDT *treeADT;

treeNode* addTreeHelper(treeNode**, treeElement);
void addTree(treeADT, treeElement);
int destroyTree(treeADT);
int destroyTreeHelper(treeNode*);
void createTree(treeADT*);
void printTree(treeADT);
void printTreeHelper(treeNode*);
```

Implementation `tree.c`

```
treeNode* addTreeHelper(treeNode **root, treeElement element){

  if(!*root){
    treeNode *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    temp->element = element;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;

    /*
    *root =  malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    (*root)->element = element;
    (*root)->left = NULL;
    (*root)->right = NULL;
    */
    *root = temp;
    return *root;
  }

  if( (*root)->element >= element ){
    addTreeHelper( &(*root)->left, element);
  }
  else{
    addTreeHelper(&(*root)->right, element);
  }

  return *root;
}

void addTree(treeADT tree, treeElement element){
  addTreeHelper(&(tree->root), element);
}

int destroyTree(treeADT tree){
  destroyTreeHelper(tree->root);
  free(tree);
  return 0;
}

int destroyTreeHelper(treeNode* root){
  if(root){
    destroyTreeHelper(root->left);
    destroyTreeHelper(root->right);
    free(root);
  }
  return 0;
}

void createTree(treeADT* tree){
  *tree = malloc(sizeof(treeCDT));
  if(!*tree){
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem allocating tree");
  }
}

void printTree(treeADT tree){
  printTreeHelper(tree->root);  
}


void printTreeHelper(treeNode * node){
  if(node){
    printf("%c\n", node->element);
    if(node->left)
      printTreeHelper(node->left);
    if(node->right)
      printTreeHelper(node->right);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Helper functions**

  should not be exposed to the client. Do not declare them in `tree.h`, and make them static to `tree.c`.
- **`treeAddHelper`**

  is surprisingly hard to follow, mostly because it returns `root` by value *and* via an argument. Select one method, preferably returning by value:

  ```
  if (root == NULL)
      return new_tree_node(element);
  if (element < root->element)
      root->left = treeAddHelper(element);
  else
      root->right = treeAddHelper(element);
  return root;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I refactored the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**API Changes**

Currently, as a user of your tree, I have to figure out whether or not I need to call `addTree`, `destroyTree`, `printTree` or their corresponding helper functions. These helper functions are *implementation* details of the tree and they should not be exposed to the user. Ditto with the `treeNode` struct. Moreover, if you will be dynamically allocating your tree, you should just be doing so inside the `createTree` function and then returning that pointer back to the user. I also don't see a need for the typedef to a `struct treeCDT *`. I personally prefer knowing what the exact type I'm dealing with here and `treeADT` really doesn't tell me anything. Your header file really should be this:

**BST.h**

```
typedef char treeElement;
struct treeCDT;

void addTree(struct treeCDT *, treeElement);
void destroyTree(struct treeCDT *);
struct treeCDT *createTree();
void printTree(struct treeCDT *);
```

Then, in your implementation file, you can implement all your helpers and mark them as `static`; this way, your user cannot call them from outside code. You can now define your `treeNode` and `treeCT` struct here as well:

**BST.c**

```
typedef struct TreeNodeTag{
    treeElement  element;
    struct TreeNodeTag  *left, *right;
} treeNode;

typedef struct treeCDT {
    // ...
} treeADT;

static void addTreeHelper(treeNode**, treeElement)
{

}

static void destroyTreeHelper(treeNode*)
{

}

static void printTreeHelper(treeNode*)
{

}
```

**Bug**

You have an error that can cause undefined behavior in your create tree function:

```
void createTree(treeADT* tree){
  *tree = malloc(sizeof(treeCDT)); // error here.
  if(!*tree){
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem allocating tree");
  }
}
```

Remember that `malloc` returns a pointer to memory without initializing it; in other words, the values could be anything! Therefore, the value in the `root` member of your `treeADT` is not initialized to NULL like it should be. (See below for alternate implementation).

**Factor your code out**

As it is now, your implementation is pretty limited as there are no searching, removing, or other utility functions. You can imagine that there will be a need to constantly create new tree nodes. I would make that a function (and mark it static).

```
static treeNode *createTreeNode(treeElement elem)
{
    treeNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(*node));
    if (node){
        node->element = elem;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Now your tree creation function can be:

```
struct treeCDT *createTree()
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(struct treeCDT));
}
```

and the insertion function is trivial now:

```
void addTree(struct treeCDT *tree, treeElement elem)
{
     if (!tree) { return; }

     if (!(tree->root)) {
         tree->root = createTreeNode(elem);
     } else {
         struct treeCDT *copy = tree->root;
         int inserted = 0;

         while (!inserted) {
             if (elem < copy->element) {
                 if (copy->left)
                     copy = copy->left;
                 else {
                     copy->left = createTreeNode(elem);
                     inserted = 1;
                 }
             } else if (elem > copy->element) {
                 if (copy->right)
                     copy = copy->right;
                 else {
                     copy->right = createTreeNode(elem);
                     inserted = 1;
                 }
             } else {
                 inserted = 1;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fore taking your time to comment on the code. A lot of your suggestions make sense. I never really understood the need for treeADT `typedef` in the tutorial I [followed](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/bst/). Also I didn't know that `static` is often used to keep functions private. 

Good catch on the malloc bug too :)

Comment: I liked the iterative insert function too.  Somehow with trees, I often think in-terms of recursive functions.